# How can I find the arguments in a php function?

Tags: php

I know how to check with `func_num_args` for the number of arguments for a function, but how can I get these arguments inside the php function:

```
<?php
function test() {
        echo func_num_args(); //returns 2
        echo $argv[1]; //this doesn't work
}

test("aa","bb");

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `func_get_args()` to obtain the array of arguments passed to the function.

For your example, simply add

```
$args = func_get_args();
```

And it should work as intended.

There also is `func_get_arg`, which returns a single argument:

```
echo func_get_arg(1); // prints second argument
```

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 5.6+ you can use: `...` like this:

```
function xy(...$args) {

    foreach($args as $arg)
        echo $arg . "<br />";

}
```

For more information about this see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list